# Copy unique number of rows separated with an empty row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

.
Hi!

I have a long list with with names of customers (>500 rows, 12 column), separated with an empty row. It looks something like this:

[image: List of customers]

I need to copy all rows for each unique customer (e.g. "Peter") to another sheets. I tried to record a macro and used combinations of **ctrl** and **shift** with **up/down/right** arrows to copy values for each customer and then jump to the next customers.

I tried to generate a generic code for the first three customers in the list (Peter, Adam, Sara) and paste the values in a another sheet.  I got the following code:

```
Sub COPY_CUSTOMERS()
'
' COPY_CUSTOMERS Makro
'

'
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet(2)").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A8").Select
    Sheets("Customers").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet(2)").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Customers").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet(2)").Select
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Customers").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End Sub
```

For customers that appear only in one row, the following code cannot be applied:

`Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select`

Thus I am not sure how to solve this problem, to select unique values since the row numbers are always different.

I would be very grateful for any help or tips.

Thanks and best regards,

QuarterlyReport

Comment: I'm not understanding something.  Do you want each customer on a separate sheet?  If not, just copy the entire table.

Comment: Have a look at [`Range.CurrentRegion`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion). It can save a couple of lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want each customer on a separate sheet.

Since I see down arrows in the top row, I have assumed your data is in a Table (ListObject in VBA).  If that is not the case, the code may require some alteration.

I've also made some other assumptions

**Algorithm**

- create unique list of Customers using a Dictionary Object
- Filter the table for each Customer

  - Write the visible cells to the Customer's worksheet
  - I have assumed the Customer worksheet name is the same as the Customer Name
  - If that sheet does not exist, it will be created.
  - The destination to paste is set at `A9`

    - But if something as been previously pasted there, we will paste below the current data, omitting the header row.

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitCustomersToSheets()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim LO As ListObject, dCust As Object
    Dim v, w, C As Range
    
Set dCust = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dCust.comparemode = vbTextCompare 'case insensitive
    
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set LO = wsSrc.ListObjects("tblCustomers") 'or whatever

'Generate list of customers
'faster to loop through vba array than through range on the worksheet
v = LO.DataBodyRange.Columns(2)
For Each w In v
    Select Case w <> ""
        Case True
            If Not dCust.exists(w) Then dCust.Add w, w
    End Select
Next w

'Copy each name to it's own worksheet
For Each v In dCust.keys

    'if worksheet not present, add it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsDest = Worksheets(v)
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
             ActiveSheet.Name = v
             Set wsDest = Worksheets(v)
        Case Is <> 0
            MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With wsDest
    Set C = .Cells(9, 1)
        If C <> "" Then 'already stuff on the page, paste below range
            Set C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With
    
    'copy the data
    LO.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    LO.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=v
    
    'if sheet not empty, then don't copy the header row
    If C.Row = 9 Then
        LO.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy C
    Else
        LO.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy C
    End If
        
Next v

End Sub
```

If your data is **NOT** in a real Excel Table, then you can try this code instead:

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitCustomersToSheets()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range, dCust As Object
    Dim v, w, C As Range
    Dim lR As Long, lC As Long
    
Set dCust = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dCust.comparemode = vbTextCompare 'case insensitive
    
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet2")
With wsSrc
    lR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lR, lC))
End With
    
'Generate list of customers
'faster to loop through vba array than through range on the worksheet
v = R.Columns(2).Offset(1, 0)
For Each w In v
    Select Case w <> ""
        Case True
            If Not dCust.exists(w) Then dCust.Add w, w
    End Select
Next w

'Copy each name to it's own worksheet
For Each v In dCust.keys

    'if worksheet not present, add it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsDest = Worksheets(v)
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
             ActiveSheet.Name = v
             Set wsDest = Worksheets(v)
        Case Is <> 0
            MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With wsDest
    Set C = .Cells(9, 1)
        If C <> "" Then 'already stuff on the page, paste below range
            Set C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With
    
    'copy the data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next 'in case no filter is set
        wsSrc.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    R.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=v
    
    'if sheet not empty, then don't copy the header row
    If C.Row = 9 Then
        R.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy C
    Else
        R.Offset(1, 0).Resize(R.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy C
    End If
        
Next v

End Sub
```

Comment: it worked! Thanks a lot!! 
Just curious: How long did it take you to write those codes? :D

Comment: @QuarterlyReport The techniques are all those that I have used in the past, so maybe 10-15 minutes.  The longer part was understanding what you wanted, since it wasn't entirely clear to me in your original question.  By the way, with the code I provide, there is no need for blank rows between customers, and the customers do not have to be grouped together.

Comment: Wow so fast! 
Oh ok, I tried to be as clear as possible. But will try to be even more clear next time. Thank again,

Comment: @QuarterlyReport It may have been clear to others, but sometimes I need things spelled out before I get it.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Btw, I would like to tweek the second code just a little bit. Could you help?

Comment: @QuarterlyReport What is the problem? If it is major, it might be better served by a new question. If minor, perhaps here.

Comment: Ok, I'll write it here and you can decide. The 2nd code is working perfectly copies just what I want where I want it.
However, I wish the the customers be copied to pre-existing sheets  (called "Blad"  in Swedish ) Blad, B(2)...Blad(100). I have a templete in those sheets and would like the customers be inserted in cell A9 in those pre-existing sheets, without the template to be deleted...
I hope this was clear and let me know if it's a major question. Thanks in advance. I know it can be tiresome when noobs ask questions!

Comment: Hi again. Ron, I managed to solve the problem!
Did it in a very crude and not so pretty way recording macros, but it gets the work done! Thank you again for your time. I learned a lot from you. Cheers.

Comment: @QuarterlyReport I'd think you could either use a worksheet template when you create a new worksheet; or, when you create the new worksheet, create the "fixed part" of it also before copying the data over.

Comment: Ok, I'll try! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that your destination sheets already exist:

```
Sub croupier()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        If v <> "" Then
            j = Sheets(v).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(v).Cells(j, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If the destination sheets have a header row, it will not be over-written.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! However, as I step through the code, I cannot see any cells being selected/copied and I get a message "Range outside border" ?

As for the sheets; I have one sheet per customer [`sheet, sheet(2), sheet(3) ...sheet(n)` etc] and they should all be pasted in cell A9. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @QuarterlyReport this is the kind of detail which should be included in the problem statement, not in a comment below an answer

Comment: @AlexM Yes, you are absolutely right. I will try to keep that in mind. Thanks!